# Querying XML in Java relationally

Tags: java

How do I do this in Java ? I have this XML ...

All I want to do is ...

If TypeCode =Country & Code1 =Ger
Return Germany ( the value of Value1)

If TypeCode =Country & Code1 =De
Return Deutschland( the value of Value2)

If TypeCode =Country && (Code1 =De & Code1 =Ger)
Return Germany ( the value of Value1) AND
Return Deutschland( the value of Value2)

```
<Entities>
   <EntityType TypeCode="Country">
      <Code1>Ger</Code1>
      <Code2>De</Code2>
      <Value1>Germany</Value1>
      <Value2>Deutschland</Value2>
      <Default>GERMANY</Default>
   </EntityType>
   <EntityType TypeCode="Country">
      <Code1>Ger</Code1>
      <Code2>De</Code2>
      <Value1>Germany</Value1>
      <Value2>Deutschland</Value2>
      <Default>GERMANY</Default>
   </EntityType>
</Entities>
```

Any snippet will be helpful

Comment: Put this in your question please, not in a comment.

Comment: Is it always harcoded for Germany as a country. Apart from DE and GER will you have other combinations ?

Comment: share the code that you have tried. Also let us know how is the API supposed to return 2 values in third case

Comment: I may have made the values redundant , it will not always be germany. The values will keep changing

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most robust way to do this in Java would be to use JAX-B (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). You gain many advantages by using JAX-B, the most important of which are

- automatic marshalling/conversion of POJOs into XML files
- automatic unmarshalling from XML files into POJOs
- XSD validation (if're using an XSD schema)
- POJO class generation from an XSD file

Now, a simple implementation of your example would be

**Entity POJO**

```
    **import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Entities")
public class Entity {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<EntityTyp> EntityType ;


     public List<EntityTyp> getEntityType() {
            if (EntityType == null) {
                EntityType = new ArrayList<EntityTyp>();
            }
            return EntityType;
        }
}**
```

**EntityTyp POJO**

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class EntityTyp {
     @XmlAttribute(name = "TypeCode", required = true)
        private String TypeCode; 
         @XmlElement 
        private String Code1;
            @XmlElement 
        private String Code2;
             @XmlElement 
        private String Value1;
             @XmlElement 
        private String Value2;
             @XmlElement 
        private String Default;

        public String getCode1(){
            return Code1;
        }
        public String getCode2(){
            return Code2;
        }
        public String getVal1(){
            return Value1;
        }
        public String getVal2(){
            return Value2;
        }
        public String getDefault(){
            return Default;
        }
        public String getTypeCode(){
            return TypeCode;
        }
        public void setCode1(String code){
            Code1 = code;
        }
        public void setCode2(String code){
            Code2 = code;
        }
        public void setVal1(String val){
            Value1 = val;
        }
        public void setVal2(String val){
            Value2 = val;
        }
        public void setDefault(String val){
            Default = val;
        }
        public void setTypeCode(String val){
            TypeCode = val;
        }


}
```

**And finally , EntityTester (used for testing)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


import jaxb.schema.src.Entities;


    *import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

        public class EntityTester {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             final String ENT_XML = "C:\\test\\Entity.xml";

                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity.class);

                  Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

                  Entity ent = (Entity) um.unmarshal(new File(ENT_XML));

                  for( EntityTyp et : ent.getEntityType() ){
                      System.out.println( et.getCode1());
                      System.out.println( et.getVal1());
                  }
            }

        }*
```

The output is

```
 Ger
Germany
Ger
Germany
```

Just make sure that you create an JAXB project so that you have all the dependencies (jars)